# How to embed complex html in facebook page

Tags: html, facebook, embed

I need to embed HTML and Js in my facebook page posts. I have found some FB apps that create iframes but i don't know if it's better to create a FB app using opengraph. Which is the correct way to embed complex HTML with scripts?

Answer (score 3):

> Which is the correct way to embed complex HTML with scripts?

There is no way.

Currently only a limited set of Facebook partners can put HTML content in an iframe into timeline posts.

All you can embed right now, via Open Graph meta tags, is videos – either flash/swf, or mp4. (If you embed flash, you can do other things than just show videos. But that won’t be supported on most mobiles, of course.)

Comment: I've asked it because i've seen that these guys made it: https://www.facebook.com/interludevideo

Comment: Well they are probably a Facebook partner then.

Comment: @Cris, they [Interlude Video] seem to be using the Facebook player to me... Did you see something different in April? PS: I don't know how Facebook are gunna allow any wild "custom JS code" to run within their posts (someone will soon turn that priviledge into a problem for everybody)

Answer (score -1):

This task is very simple to perform, and is built into Meta posts.
If you want to embed a person, page or group, start typing with the '@' sign, then the name of the page, group or person.
If you want to embed a website, just copy its address (URL) into the body of the post.